# Pen is not rotating with screen after upgrade to Lunar Lobster (Lenova X1 Yoga gen 6)

Tags: lenovo, 23.04, stylus

I am using a Lenova X1 Yoga gen 6 - convertible laptop with finger and pen touch inputs.

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 - autorotate works but the pen input does not change orientation, so is unusable in portrait mode. Finger touch input rotates correctly.

I tried booting with kernel 5.19, but got the same results.

Edit: I discovered that things work as expected if I select the built-in display (eDP-1) under "Map to Monitor" in Wacom Tablet settings, instead of "All Displays" (I didn't have any external display connected).

Comment: See the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017322?comments=all, and please mark yourself as affected!

Comment: thanks for the workaround, which works for my Dell Latitude 7320 detachable.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a known [problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi-support/+bug/217182) for over a decade. I don't believe it's ever been fixed.

One workaround is to use the `xsetwacom` command to "rotate" the touch interface as outlined in this [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi-support/+bug/217182/comments/4) in bug [217182](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi-support/+bug/217182).

```
xsetwacom set stylus rotate X
xsetwacom set cursor rotate X
xsetwacom set eraser rotate X
```

Where X is

- cw --> for 180º rotate
- ccw --> for portrait use
- none --> for normal use

`xsetwacom` is provided by `wacom-tools` package.

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite sure this was working for me with Wayland and 22.04 (and see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1118 for example). I haven't been able to manually rotate the touch interface with Wayland (xinput doesn't completely do the trick). Workaround with xsetwacom or similar works fine with X.

Comment: just a dump from when I had an HP X360 with touchscreen. .. xrandr --output eDP --rotate left &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP 
the 14 might change. that was for inverted. normal was "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    left  0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1  right  0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1